# How do I use enumerate in Python to compute STD of a list?

Tags: python, enumerate, standard-deviation

I'm trying to compute the standard deviation of a list `vr`. The list size is 32, containing an array of size 3980. This array represents a value at a given `height` (3980 heights).

First I split the data into 15 minute chunks, where the minutes are given in `raytimes`. `raytimes` is a list of size `32` as well (containing just the time of the observation, `vr`).

I want the standard deviation computed at each `height` level, such that I end up with one final array of size `3980`. This happens OK in my code. However my code does not produce the correct standard deviation value when I test it — that is to say the values that are output to `w1sd`, `w2sd` etc, are not correct (however the array is the correct size: an array of `3980` elements). I assume I am mixing up the wrong indices when computing the standard deviation.

Below are example values from the dataset. All data should fall into `w1` and `w1sd` as the `raytimes` provided in this example are all within 15 minutes (< 0.25). I want to compute the standard deviation of the first element of `vr`, that is, the standard deviation of `2.0 + 3.1 + 2.1`, then the second element, or standard deviation of `3.1 + 4.1 + nan` etc. 
The result for `w1sd` SHOULD BE `[0.497, 0.499, 1.0, 7.5]` but instead the code as below gives a `nanstd` in `w1sd = [0.497, 0.77, 1.31, 5.301]`. Is it something wrong with `nanstd` or my indexing?

```
vr = [
    [2.0, 3.1, 4.1, nan],
    [3.1, 4.1, nan, 5.1],
    [2.1, nan, 6.1, 20.1]
]
Height = [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40]
raytimes = [0, 0.1, 0.2]

for j, h in enumerate(Height): 
    for i, t in enumerate(raytimes):
        if raytimes[i] < 0.25:
            w1.append(float(vr[i][j]))
        elif 0.25 <= raytimes[i] < 0.5:
            w2.append(float(vr[i][j]))
        elif 0.5 <= raytimes[i] < 0.75:
            w3.append(float(vr[i][j]))
        else:
            w4.append(float(vr[i][j]))
    w1sd.append(round(nanstd(w1), 3))
    w2sd.append(round(nanstd(w2), 3))
    w3sd.append(round(nanstd(w3), 3))
    w4sd.append(round(nanstd(w4), 3))
    w1 = []
    w2 = []
    w3 = []
    w4 = []
```

Comment: `raytimes[i]` should just be `t`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Height` list? You're never using `h` or `Height[j]`. That loop could just be `for j in range(len(Height)):`

Comment: raytimes[i] should be t -- OK thank you, but the STD values I get at the end are still wrong.
Sure, I can change the loop just for j in range(len(Height)), but I believe my computation of the STD values are still wrong?
Point is I think I'm using enumerate wrong as it produces the wrong values for STD (w1sd) at the end

Comment: None of my comments have anything to do with the results, they're just stylistic.

Comment: OK thanks. But if someone can point to why my computation of the STD at each height level is wrong in the above scheme....?

Comment: Can you show some sample data and the expected results?

Comment: Sure, I have provided example data, result for w1sd, and expected result for w1sd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) for this. It is a library that allows for efficient processing of datasets in `numpy` arrays and takes all the looping and indexing out of your hands.

In this case I would define a `dataframe` with `N_raytimes` rows and `N_Height` columns, which would allow to easily slice and aggregate the data any way you like.

This code gives the expected output.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

vr = [
    [2.0, 3.1, 4.1, np.nan],
    [3.1, 4.1, np.nan, 5.1],
    [2.1, np.nan, 6.1, 20.1]
]
Height = [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40]
raytimes = [0, 0.1, 0.2]

# Define a dataframe with the data
df = pd.DataFrame(vr, columns=Height, index=raytimes)
df.columns.name = "Height"
df.index.name = "raytimes"

# Split it out (this could be more elegant)
w1 = df[df.index < 0.25]
w2 = df[(df.index >= 0.25) & (df.index < 0.5)]
w3 = df[(df.index >= 0.5) & (df.index < 0.75)]
w4 = df[df.index >= 0.75]

# Compute standard deviations
w1sd = w1.std(axis=0, ddof=0).values
w2sd = w2.std(axis=0, ddof=0).values
w3sd = w3.std(axis=0, ddof=0).values
w4sd = w4.std(axis=0, ddof=0).values
```